# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in. Solución urgente, por favor

Tags: php

Se supone que con este código PhP el  usuario ingrese su Nick y su contraseña y yo lo almacene en una base de datos, pero al momento que el usuarioo los ingresa, aparece ste error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Mi código es

```
<?php
    $db =  MySQLi_connect("localhost", "u554150303_logos","", "u554150303_logos");
    //echo "Conexión exitossa!";
    //$link =mysqli_connect("localhost","u554150303_logos","mendoza98");
    //if($link){
    //    mysqli_select_db($link,"academ");
    //}
    if(isset($_POST['realname'])) {
        $realname=$_POST['realname'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];
    }

    require("connect_db.php");
    //la variable $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");       
    //require("connect_db.php");
    //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $query=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO login VALUES('','$realname','$pass','2')");
    //echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
    echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';
?>
```

Comment: Verificaste que te lleguen los dos parametros? Porque el error es q estan llegando menos parametros que los que la funcion necesita.

Comment: $query=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO login VALUES('','$realname','$pass','2')");

Answer (score 0):

seguí las indicaciones de Shadow y desapareció el error, sin embargo, a pesar de que el usuario se registra "correctamente" no se guardan los datos en la base. ¿Alguna idea? Es que, repito, soy nuevo en ésto de la programación

Comment: tienes 2 perfiles Andres? es decir Marvin también es tu usuario o como?

Comment: No, solo que hice la publicación como invitado y luego me registré en la página. Mi nombre es Marvin Andrés, jaja

Answer (score -1):

Soy totalmente nuevo en ésto e la programación, así que te diré que el error se presenta en la línea 31 del código

Comment: y como sabes que linea es la 31 ?

Comment: Porque al momento que se presenta el error,e me dice que lo produce la línea 31, pero seguí las indicaciones de Shadow y desapareciço el error, sin embargo, a pesar de que el usuario se registra "correctamente" no  se guardan los datos en la base. ¿Alguna idea? Es que, repito, soy nuevo en ésto de la programación

Comment: hazle un `var_dump($query);`  dale editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que obtengas de hacer lo que te digo

Comment: Ammm, ¿Podrías explicarme en español? Jajaja, te repito. Soy nuevo, apenas soy estudiante de ésto y es la primera vez que programo